# I can't use pip (Windows)

Tags: python, pip, command-prompt

I'm wanting to learn machine learning, but it requires that I use 'pip.' I'm still very new to a lot of this stuff. I've installed Python 3.4 64-bit and get-py.py.

When I run `pip install sklearn` I get `'pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

Here's a screenshot of my environmental variable PATH

https://gyazo.com/c7ec926401878845d5c4f9a556cf00ee

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I have checked out other posts where people had similar issues, but I tried various things and nothing worked.

Answer (score 13):

I downloaded Python 3.6 and the pip was installed on my system.
I found pip at below location:

```
C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Scripts
```

Also, before I found pip I used below command on my command prompt to install pyperclip:

```
python -m pip install pyperclip
```

Answer (score 10):

Easiest solution is to just download a platform like Anaconda for example. It is Python with many libraries (sklearn, pandas, numpy, ...) and also with pip, all in a user-friendly Windows installer package, that takes care of everything for you.

https://www.continuum.io/downloads

If you really want to do it yourself, then

1. download get-pip.py (https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py)
2. make sure you have Python installed and in your PATH, for example by running `python --version` in command prompt
3. Navigate to the directory, where you downloaded get-pip.py (in command prompt using the command `cd`).
4. Run the command `python get-pip.py` from a command prompt with admin privileges (possibly not needed, but just to make sure).
5. This should be all. Close your command prompt, open it again and run `pip --version` to test it. If it doesn't work, then search your computer for a file named `pip.exe` (most likely in your Python directory) and if you find it, add its path to your PATH variable (given the screenshot, I assume you know how to do this).

Comment: Nicely explained, but instead of just adding pip to PATH, it's better to add the entire python-directory (which should include pip in the later versions) to PATH.

Answer (score 3):

For anyone that might have installed Python using the MSI installer, and ticked the box to include `pip`, but still gets the error `'pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file`:

It looks like that the `pip` executable is installed in the `\Scripts` subdirectory of the Python installation, but that directory does not get automatically added to PATH.

For me, since I had installed Python 2.7, the directory was `C:\Python27\Scripts`. After adding this path to the `PATH` environment variable, and open a new CMD window, pip was available as a command.

Answer (score 2):

I've made a workaround that will help you, copy the batch script below and modify it as specified:

```
@"PATH to python.exe" "PATH to pip.exe" %*
```

For example like this:

```
@"C:\programming\bin\python374\python.exe" "C:\programming\bin\python374\Scripts\pip.exe" %*
```

Save this file as pip.bat on Desktop and then move it to C:\Windows\system32.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This is late but in case anyone runs across this issue, pip installed for me as "pip3". Once I used pip3 as my command and not pip, it worked fine. Threw me for quite a loop since I've been using Python for years.

Answer (score 1):

I'm late now, but just add python to your environment variables.

It´s explained in this short video, how to set up python to your environment variables:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y2q_b4ugPWk

after that pip should work on your cmd prompt, without cd to
"C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Scripts"

Comment: while this probably answers the question, please consider the fact that linked content tends to disappear. So please have your answer reflect the gist of the content you link to.

Answer (score 1):

For Python 3.7 or higher at least (as today is October 4th 2019) in the installation window you need to check the box "add to PATH" when you first install Python.

Answer (score 1):

[PIP Install and Upgrade](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZBXo0.png)

Ensure you are accessing the right location while accessing pip as shown in my link above. Starting Python 3.4, it is included by default with the Python binary installers.

[Environment Variable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6hdFG.png)
It is also a good idea to update the environment variable if the path is not accessible by default, once the installation is complete.

Answer (score 0):

If it is specifically pip you want you could install python again making sure to tick the install pip box which it sounds like you failed to upon initial installation.

Comment: I've installed Python over and over again 5 times already. Pip was selected every time. I'm now attempting to install Anaconda.

Comment: Okay sorry. python doesn't appear in your path. try adding C:\Python34 to your path assuming it was a default installation.

Comment: The installation of Anaconda was successful and Pip now works. However, running .py files in atom using atom-runner I get an error:

https://gyazo.com/4ee871cfe9deb3a391bceb47555b0c9d

Answer (score 0):

Just to make sure you're not doing this (because I did it an embarrassing number of times), DO NOT USE PIP INSIDE THE PYTHON INTERPRETER.

When you're doing basically any command with Python that is NOT some piece of code like `a = 5`, use Command Prompt (or sometimes, if really necessary, use Powershell). If you're coding, then use the Python Interpreter (the icon that has the Python snake symbol).

### Below is mainly for Windows users, but maybe it'll be useful to others too.

The first thing you should attempt is opening Command Prompt from anywhere (either clicking on File Explorer's file-address bar or pressing the Windows key, then typing in `cmd`, then pressing enter).
Next, type in `pip install sklearn` or replace `sklearn` with whatever package you want to download.

If you installed a previous version of Python at some point in time (possibly without you even knowing), it was probably some version of Python2, which loves to place all its folders in low-level (high-level?) (base) directories (like `C:\` or `C:\Users\` or `C:\Users\<your_username>\`).

I found `pip.exe` inside of this Scripts folder at this location:
`C:\Users\<your_username>\Scripts`

I think that whenever you attempt to execute a command in Command Prompt, regardless of whether it's present in your path environment variable (this pip.exe was not present in my paths at all), Command Prompt searches from the lowest-level (highest-level?) directories and works its way deeper. Older versions of Python installed in the lowest directories, so they're found first.

After I installed newer versions of Python (Python3.x), it seemed like I couldn't use any commands in the way that I should be able to, even after modifying path.
For example, I tried `pip install numpy` but Command Prompt told me

`Requirement already satisfied: numpy in c:\users\<username>\lib\site-packages (1.26.0)`

It turns out that it was finding Python2's installed version of numpy, which isn't what any of my other programs needed (or the location was unfindable/invisible by my other programs). So, I had to delete Python2's pip installer so that Command Prompt wouldn't assume I wanted Python2's pip installer when I ran `pip install numpy`, which required deleting
`C:\Users\<your_username>\Scripts\pip.exe`

#### tl;dr

If you can't "pip install" something and you might have another version of python installed somewhere on your computer, then do `where python` or `where pip` or `where` ... in your command prompt and check if you have more than one version of the same filename. If you do have more than one, try altering your path (System Environment Variables) to point to the specific version you want to use; however, this doesn't always work. If it doesn't work, then use that Command Prompt output (the filepaths) from `where` ... to find and remove conflicting versions of python executables.