# Can not use pip install on Windows 10

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, pip, python-3.9

When I was trying to install PyQt5 on Windows 10, I got the following error:

```
C:\Users\USER_NAME>pip install PyQt5
ERROR: Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\andrew\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\base_command.py", line 180, in _main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "c:\users\andrew\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\req_command.py", line 205, in wrapper
    return func(self, options, args)
  File "c:\users\andrew\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\commands\install.py", line 318, in run
    requirement_set = resolver.resolve(
  File "c:\users\andrew\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\resolvelib\resolver.py", line 127, in resolve
    result = self._result = resolver.resolve(
  File "c:\users\andrew\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\resolvelib\resolvers.py", line 473, in resolve
    state = resolution.resolve(requirements, max_rounds=max_rounds)
  File "c:\users\andrew\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\resolvelib\resolvers.py", line 341, in resolve
    name, crit = self._merge_into_criterion(r, parent=None)
  File "c:\users\andrew\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\resolvelib\resolvers.py", line 172, in _merge_into_criterion
    if not criterion.candidates:
  File "c:\users\andrew\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\resolvelib\structs.py", line 139, in __bool__
    return bool(self._sequence)
  File "c:\users\andrew\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\resolvelib\found_candidates.py", line 143, in __bool__
    return any(self)
  File "c:\users\andrew\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\resolvelib\found_candidates.py", line 129, in <genexpr>
    return (c for c in iterator if id(c) not in self._incompatible_ids)
  File "c:\users\andrew\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\resolvelib\found_candidates.py", line 30, in _iter_built
    for version, func in infos:
  File "c:\users\andrew\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\resolvelib\factory.py", line 269, in iter_index_candidate_infos
    result = self._finder.find_best_candidate(
  File "c:\users\andrew\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\index\package_finder.py", line 879, in find_best_candidate
    candidates = self.find_all_candidates(project_name)
  File "c:\users\andrew\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\index\package_finder.py", line 824, in find_all_candidates
    page_candidates = list(page_candidates_it)
  File "c:\users\andrew\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\index\sources.py", line 134, in page_candidates
    yield from self._candidates_from_page(self._link)
  File "c:\users\andrew\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\index\package_finder.py", line 783, in process_project_url
    html_page = self._link_collector.fetch_page(project_url)
  File "c:\users\andrew\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\index\collector.py", line 512, in fetch_page
    return _get_html_page(location, session=self.session)
  File "c:\users\andrew\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\index\collector.py", line 422, in _get_html_page
    resp = _get_html_response(url, session=session)
  File "c:\users\andrew\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\index\collector.py", line 120, in _get_html_response
    resp = session.get(
  File "c:\users\andrew\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\sessions.py", line 555, in get
    return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
  File "c:\users\andrew\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\network\session.py", line 449, in request
    return super().request(method, url, *args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\users\andrew\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\sessions.py", line 542, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "c:\users\andrew\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\sessions.py", line 655, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "c:\users\andrew\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\cachecontrol\adapter.py", line 53, in send
    resp = super(CacheControlAdapter, self).send(request, **kw)
  File "c:\users\andrew\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\adapters.py", line 439, in send
    resp = conn.urlopen(
  File "c:\users\andrew\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 696, in urlopen
    self._prepare_proxy(conn)
  File "c:\users\andrew\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 964, in _prepare_proxy
    conn.connect()
  File "c:\users\andrew\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\connection.py", line 359, in connect
    conn = self._connect_tls_proxy(hostname, conn)
  File "c:\users\andrew\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\connection.py", line 500, in _connect_tls_proxy
    return ssl_wrap_socket(
  File "c:\users\andrew\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\util\ssl_.py", line 432, in ssl_wrap_socket
    ssl_sock = _ssl_wrap_socket_impl(sock, context, tls_in_tls)
  File "c:\users\andrew\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\util\ssl_.py", line 474, in _ssl_wrap_socket_impl
    return ssl_context.wrap_socket(sock)
  File "c:\users\andrew\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\ssl.py", line 500, in wrap_socket
    return self.sslsocket_class._create(
  File "c:\users\andrew\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\ssl.py", line 997, in _create
    raise ValueError("check_hostname requires server_hostname")
ValueError: check_hostname requires server_hostname
```

I have tried all the methods on [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56418874/cant-install-pyqt5-using-pip) and none of them helps. What could be the problem here? I have spent a lot of time on this. Thank you so much!!!

I don't have a proxy server on my system, does it matter? It might not be the problem of PyQt5. It might be the problem of my system.

Answer (score 0):

I would try downloading anaconda, it has the pyQt5 environment, also when downloading / installing, make sure you click the update path option.

Comment: I don't think this is due to pyqt5 environment because I get the extact same error when I run `python -m pip install --upgrade pip` Bascially, this error appears everytime I try to install using pip

Comment: I dont know, I had a previous similar problem, so got rid of my current installation and use anaconda, because all the best libraries ect, are there on a dashboard, one button click away.

Answer (score 0):

Go through these below, but it'd also be helpful if you could verify that you have pip installed correctly with `pip -V`.

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-install-pip-on-windows/
https://stackoverflow.com/a/44232032/12406158